# Having some issues in express get request

Tags: node.js, express, postgresql-9.1

I have created one app using node.js and postgresql to display the user city depending upon the requested user id.If i hit this URL in(localhosthost:7070/user/userId/city) in browser means using express get request i'm calling method to get the requested user city from database using the requested user id.I'm getting correct output without any issues.But i'm facing some other issue.

Issue

First while hitting localhost:7070/user/1/city URL in browser means it's giving the output also the result is displaying in my page.But again if i hit localhost:7070/user/2/city URL in browser means i'm not getting any error and any output but my page is always loading.So if i want to do it for other user means again i have restart my node server.Then only it works.Can anyone help me what is the exact issue.

Here i have attached my code...

server.js

```
var pg = require('pg'); 
var conString =require('./config');
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
var queryModule=require('./query');
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(7070);

console.log('Server started at port 7070.');
app.get('/user/:id/city',function(req, response){
    client.connect(function(err, result){
        if(!err){
            var userId=req.param('id');
            queryModule.findCityByUserId(client,userId,function(err,res){
                if(!err){
                    console.log('done');
                    response.send('Requested user city is '+res);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('Error while finding the city of the user ' + err);
            });
        } else {
            console.log('error while connecting client '+err);
        }
    });
 });
```

query.js

```
 function Query(){
 }

module.exports=Query;

Query.findCityByUserId = function(client, id, cb){
    client.query("SELECT city FROM userinfo WHERE id=" + id, function(err,res){
        if(err){
            return cb(err);
        }
        client.end();
        var row = res.rows['0'];
        console.log("row length: " + res.rows.length);
        Object.keys(row).forEach(function(key){
            cb(null, row['city']);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: One thing that seems to be missing is if you ask for auser which does not yet exist in the database you have no return only a console.log("Error while ...."); , if you dont have it further down the code you need to give the user a response here or otherwise the browser will freeze for a long time waiting for a response which will never be returned.

Comment: @Todilo im checking record for the existing user only..

Comment: Try passing conString to `client.connect`. I am thinking it is taking as defaults after `client.end` is called.

Comment: @user568109 i have tried but that's not working becaues findCityByUserId method is not calling in 2nd time..again after restarting the node server only that method is calling..

Answer (score -1):

I just got started with node.

The problem may be that you're not ending your response with res.end();